# Code in C language does not work as expected

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, while-loop, scanf

I am having trouble solving this exercise regarding vectors in the C language. The question reads as follows: Make a program in C Language that declares a 10-position vector of integers and three other integers x, y, and z. Next, the program must receive three input integers and store them respectively in the variables x, y, and z, validating the variable y such that 0 < y <= 10. Next, the program must place the value contained in x in the first y positions of the vector (positions of index 0 through y-1) , assigning the value contained in z to the remaining positions (of index y through 9). Finally, display the resulting vector on the screen, separating the values with a blank space.

Example:

| Input | Output |
| --- | --- |
| 3 4 -2 | 3 3 3 3 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 |
| 2 7 6 | 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 6 6 6 |
| 1 -1 2 9 | 1 1 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 |
| 1 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5 2 2 | 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 |

When I run the code and enter in the input these first two examples of numbers that are in the table above (3 4 -2) and (2 7 6) it gives exactly the result that is expected for these two examples, as stated in the table.

The problem is giving when I type in the input these last two examples that are in the table (1 -1 -2 2 9) and (1 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5 2 2). In the output, the results are totally different from what is expected in the table above. In the second to last example, the output is 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2, and in the last example, the output is 1 1 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2. I don't know if it is something to do with the amount of numbers that were entered in the input (more than 3 numbers), because in the statement it says to declare a vector of integers of **10 positions** and **three other integers x, y and z**, or also, there is something wrong in the *while* command, when validating the y.  In that, I think something is missing in my code, so that way, it presents in the output the results that are expected when you type these last two examples in the table above.

Code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    int main() {
        int vetor[10], x, y, z;

        // receiving values of x, y, and z
        scanf("%d %d %d", &x, &y, &z);

       // validating y
       while (y <= 0 || y > 10) {
           scanf("%d", &y);
       }

      // by filling the vector
      for (int i = 0; i < y; i++) {
        vetor[i] = x;
      }
      for (int i = y; i < 10; i++) {
        vetor[i] = z;
      }

      // printing the resultant vector
      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
          printf("%d ", vetor[i]);
      }
      printf("\n");

      return 0;
    }
```

If anyone can help me solve the problem, I appreciate it!

I have tried several times to modify the *while* command, putting an *if* at the time of validating the y, but I have not been successful.
I need that when I type the numbers (1 -1 2 9) in the input, it shows in the output the result 1 1 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9, all separated by a blank space.
Also, if I type the numbers (1 -1 -2 -2 -3 -4 -5 2 2) in the input, output the result 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2, all separated by a blank.

Comment: `scanf("%d %d %d", &x, &y, &z);` isn't going to work with bad `y` input. You'll end up with `z` having one of the `y` values.

Comment: As @001 said, You need to scanf the x value, then your while loop to validate y, then finally scanf for z.

Comment: "Next, the program must receive three input integers and store them respectively in the variables x, y, and z, validating the variable y such that 0 < y <= 10." I would interpret this as "you always get three inputs, and the second one must satisfy 0 < y <= 10, but clearly this interpretation is wrong, since your last two examples give more than 3 inputs.

Answer (score 2):

The problem statement is poorly written; “validating the variable y such that 0 < y <= 10” is unclear. It appears what is intended is that the program should read a value for `x`, then read a value for `y`, and, if the value for `y` does not satisfy 0 < y ≤ 10, repeat reading a value for `y` until it does, then read a value for `z`. You should modify the program to do that.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem of your code is that you at once are entering three numbers without checking whether the variable `y` has a valid value.

```
   // receiving values of x, y, and z
    scanf("%d %d %d", &x, &y, &z);
```

You should not enter a value for the variable `z` until the variable `y` gets a valid value.

You should write for example like

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ) 
{
    enum { N = 10 };

    int vetor[N], x, y, z;
    int result;


    // receiving values of x, y, and z
    while ( ( result = scanf( "%d", &x ) ) != 1 )
    {
        if ( result != EOF ) scanf( "%*[^\n]" );
    }  

    while (( result = scanf( "%d", &y ) ) != 1 || y < 1 || y > N)
    {
        if (result != EOF && result != 1 ) scanf( "%*[^\n]" );
    }

    while ( ( result = scanf( "%d", &z ) ) != 1 )
    {
        if ( result != EOF ) scanf( "%*[^\n]" );
    }  


    // by filling the vector
    for (int i = 0; i < y; i++) {
       vetor[i] = x;
    }

    for (int i = y; i < N; i++) {
       vetor[i] = z;
    }

    // printing the resultant vector
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        printf("%d ", vetor[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```